# For loop randomly stops in C

Tags: c

sorry if the title is non-specific but I wasn't too sure of how I was supposed to title this post. I'm creating a function which encrypts a given string. Here it is:

```
int ind(char c, char * t){
    int i = 0;
    while (i != strlen(t)){
        if (t[i] == c) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

void translate2 (char * c, char * ret){
    char used[1000], d;
    int i = 18, size = 0;

    for (i=0; i < strlen(c);i++){
        printf("\nChar: %c",c[i]);
        printf("arguments going in are char %c and str %s", c[i], used);
        if (ind(c[i], used) == -1){
            used[size] = c[i];
            ret[size] = c[i];
            size++;

        }
        else{
            if (ind(c[i], used) == 0){
                d = used[size];
            }
            else {d = used[ind(c[i], used)-1];}
            /*printf("Thus, our d shall be %c\n\n", d);*/
            ret[size] = d;
            size++;
        }
        printf("\nSeq: %s", used);
        printf("\nOutput: %s\n", ret);
    }
}
```

Sorry if the code is messy, I'm pretty new to this. I suppose what the code actually does isn't too important. My issue here is that, the code works as intended for the first run through the loop. Once it finishes that, the program stops. I can't figure out why this happens, and I'm not handy enough with debuggers to use them. Can anyone point me towards the right direction? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (i != strlen(t)){
    if (t[i] == c) return i;
}
```

‘i’ is not incrementing in the loop. You are indefinitely checking the first element